# Is academic writing for students Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, business

Is academic writing for students Halal?
Normally students are given assignments and they pay someone to write for them with variable payments by bargaining. Is is halal for students as well as for writers?
Students are taking services from writers and are paying them. Writers are using their skills and are getting paid.
Similarly their are content writing jobs where writers produce contents or testimonials to market a product. They dont see or use the product (like webpages, helping books) but they create attractive pragarphs praising the prodcut. In a simlar way, writers are marketing some products which are Haram (like casinos, gambling etc) using their writing skills. 
There is a whole business of freelancing on web. Is it halal for writers or Haram.
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

If I understand your question (which is not easy, as it written in atrocious English) you are asking whether it is halal to pay someone to write your school work for you. I would suggest that it is only halal if the real author puts his or her name on the piece of school work. If you put your name on it you are perpetrating a fraud.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am clarifying my question here. I am freelancer and write assignments of students using my knowledge and writing skills and get paid. Is it halal for me? Moreover I dont put my name on the school work and students submit them on their behalf.

Comment: I do not know where you live. Here in Britain forgery is a criminal offence. The Prophet of Islam taught us to search for knowledge, not to pay someone to help us to pretend to have knowledge that we do not have.

Comment: Yes the point is clear now that it is not halal. What can be done with the money I have earned so far? I cant pay back the actual client.

Comment: @AunasManzoor, distribute that money to some poor near by your house and don't expect reward for it. If there are no poor nearby, then to some charity organisations.

Comment: @AunasManzoor You are not commiting forgery though. I would argue its okay to do this as you are simply providing a service. You do work for someone and they pay you. Yes, it sucks for those who are paying you as they are committing academic dishonesty and even worse they are not learning anything but I believe you are okay if providing a service.

Comment: @aasheq it is not what he is asking. It's not that he wants to pay someone to write his schoolwork, its that someone is paying him to do it, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: @masfenix. You admit that "they are committing academic dishonesty". So why are you defending it?

Comment: @aasheq because he is not committing academic dishonesty, his customers are. And even then, we can't be sure about this and its a pretty strong assumption. For him, its just a job, which is perfectly fine.  It's the same argument as "selling a gun". Do I agree with what he's doing? I can't say I do, but that dosnt mean its haram.

Answer (score -2):

I am in the same situation. I did a lot of academic. According to me the student who is paying you is cheating with teachers and to help him is also cheating.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion if a writer is paid for his efforts which he has texted to get money than it is not haram. As for as writing a text in praise of  haram product like alcohol etc. in prohibited in Islam bcos by earning this money one is cause of promoting evil in society. ..

Comment: We don't look for your personal opinion, we look for a statement that has strong backup in the Qur'an sunnah and view of qualified and accepted scholars.